# Save message in bag File

Tags: ros, bagfile, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

How can I save a message, which change from time to time, about a certain period in a bag file? (I like to reproduce the message at this time)

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63824/save-message-in-bag-file/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can record the whole time and then use [rosbag filter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Producing%20filtered%20bag%20files) to extract the specific timestamps.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1